# How can I split Bot Framework Dialogs in different files

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework

I am trying to make my bot code a bit more manageable and put some dialogs which belong together in different files.

[There is an old, similar question here for javascript.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1457)

But I am struggling to do the same with Typescript. Probably this is more a general Typescript question as I am a beginner and still am a bit confused about the different import possibilities, but I didn't find any general solution which I was able to apply to this.

What I tried is this:

```
//testdialog.ts

export default (bot) => {
bot.dialog("/Test", [
    (session, args, next) => {
        console.log("test".green);
        session.send(`Test Dialog triggered`);
    },
]).triggerAction({ matches: "test" });
}
```

and then in app.ts import it similar to this:
`import testdialog = require("./testdialog")(bot);`

But seems like this seems completely wrong compared to an unnamed import with bot as a parameter in JS like this `require('./cars.js')(bot);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you can leverage `builder.Library()` to achieve your requirement.

```
//testdialog.ts
import * as builder from 'botbuilder';

export const createLibrary = () => {
    let lib = new builder.Library('test');
    lib.dialog('test', (session) => {
        session.send('this is test dialog');
    }).triggerAction({
        matches: /test/
    });
    return lib.clone();
}

//app.ts
import * as restify from 'restify';
import * as builder from 'botbuilder';
import * as testDialog from './testdialog';

let server = restify.createServer({});
server.listen(3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
})

let connector = new builder.ChatConnector({});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
let bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', (session) => {
    session.send('welcome');
})

bot.library(testDialog.createLibrary())
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! This should be in the bot framework documentation imo.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
// a.js
export default expression;
```

then you must write

```
// b.js
import whatever from "./a";

console.log(whatever);
```

or

```
// b.js
import * as whatever from "./a";

console.log(whatever.default);
```

or

```
// b.js
import whatever = require("./a");

console.log(whatever.default);
```

***But*** if you write

```
// a.js
export = expression;
```

then you must write

```
// b.js
import whatever = require("./a");

console.log(whatever);
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, helps a lot for my understanding.

Comment: @solaire glad to help

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong, don't use `require`, do the import like this:
`import * as testdialog from './testdialog';`

And then run your bot, like this: `testdialog(bot);`

Comment: If i try this I get the error "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature." at testdialog(bot);

Comment: Can you post the full code that gives you this error?

Comment: It is completely illegal in ECMAScript to call a module namespace object. `import * as ns` always creates such an object meaning `ns()` will result in an error. It may actually work under certain run times and transpilers is but is neither correct nor portable. The error @solaire receives is expected as this code is incorrect

Comment: Also using `require` is perfectly correct if you're using AMD, CommonJS, or UMD modules