# Including dialogs or reusing dialogs from different file

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to do begindialog from another another dialog js file. I am getting error.

```
<b>[onTurnError]: Error: DialogContext.beginDialog(): A dialog with an id of 'FollowUpDialog' wasn't found. </b>
```

this is dialog structure-

- dialogs

  1. orderstatus

     - orderstatus.js
     - index.js
  2. FollowUp

     - followUp.js
     - index.js

i am trying to include FollowUp dialog in OrderStatus Dialog, similary i have other dialogs where i want to begin followup or orderstatus dialog. trying to reuse the dialogs.

One way to do use how we include the file in botjs amd to do adddialog same way i can include in otherfile. But it is redundant work. I am trying to avoid that. Can some one tell me better approach to include the dialog in different dialogs.

**code:**

Below code is from greeting.js
If you see line where i am doing begindialog.

return await step.beginDialog(ORDER_STATUS_DIALOG);
return await step.beginDialog(ENTITLEMENT_CHECK_DIALOG);

It is error. I am trying to include the dialog which is part of different JS files.

```
        async step => {

                    if (step.context.activity.channelId == 'directline') {
                        const buttons = [{
                            type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
                            title: 'Repair Order Status',
                            value: symbolicString.ZEB_GR_STR_013
                        }, {
                            type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
                            title: 'Entitlement Check',
                            value: symbolicString.ZEB_GR_STR_014
                        }];
                        const card = CardFactory.heroCard('', undefined, buttons, {
                            text: symbolicString.ZEB_GR_STR_015
                        });
                        const reply = {type: ActivityTypes.Message};
                        reply.attachments = [card];
                        return await step.context.sendActivity(reply);
                    } else {
                        return await step.prompt(MENU_PROMPT, symbolicString.ZEB_GR_STR_028);
                    }
                },
                async step => {

                    if (step.context.activity.channelId != 'directline'){
                        console.log("step greeting dialog next step");
                        console.log(step);
                        console.log(step.context.activity);
                        if (step.context.activity.text == '1'){
                            return await step.beginDialog(ORDER_STATUS_DIALOG);
                        }else if (step.context.activity.text == '2'){
                            return await step.beginDialog(ENTITLEMENT_CHECK_DIALOG);
                        }
                    }

                    return await step.endDialog();
                }
        ]));
```

Comment: I would advice to add some code to your question so you can get the help you wish plus prevent the question to be flagged and closed.

Comment: added code.. i didn't added because question was more of generic.. how to include dialogs from one file to another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split Bot Framework Dialogs in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212414/how-can-i-split-bot-framework-dialogs-in-different-files)

Comment: I had the same requirement and it was achieved using ComponentDialogs ... check this link ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-compositcontrol?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp